# Visualstudio 2012 Biztalk Addin cannot be removed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, biztalk, visual-studio-addins

Recently, I have installed the BizTalk nos ultimate Addin Trail. Now, its expired but I have trouble removing it .

I cannot be able to open the visual studio. The Addin Menu just popup and whatever I do, just ain't make me get pass through it and use the visual studio 2012. Any way to remove it ?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is a commercial product. Have you tried contacting your support?

Comment: As a last resort, you could try repairing Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If it is really an "add-in" for VS, delete the .AddIn file that should be in one of the locations listed in     [INFO: Default .AddIn file locations for Visual Studio add-ins](http://www.mztools.com/Articles/2008/MZ2008001.aspx).

It could be also a COM-based add-in instead of a XML-based add-in or it could be also a "package" for VS and not an "add-in".